# How to return base form from derived form?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have a form `FormA` that inherits from `Form`. I override `OnLoad` as follows:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    //Do FormA stuff here            
}
```

Now I derive a second form `FormB` from `FormA` so that I have the same form layout. However I want to also override `OnLoad` but if I do this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    //Do FormB stuff here        
    //without doing FormA stuff    
}
```

It would call `FormA's OnLoad` which I do not want.

In this scenario, how can I call the `Form Onload` event from within `FormB`?

Comment: If you don't want that, don't extend FormA; extend Form instead. Or create a common base class for both where you *can* call the base implementation. Inheritance is a poor model for things where you want some things from a direct base class and some other things from base classes further up the hierarchy.

Comment: I feel since on load functions of form A triggers some intialization of data  for form A which you dont want when creating form b  am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with this code. You can't say `base.base.OnLoad` for example.

I guess you want to do something like this.

*FormA*:

```
protected sealed override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    MyOnLoad(e);
}

protected virtual void MyOnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    // FormA onload
}
```

*FormB*:

```
protected override void MyOnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    // FormB onload
}
```

Here you force to always call `Form.OnLoad`, but you can change the `OnLoad` behavior per derived class in `MyOnLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the call to `base.OnLoad(e)`. However, I strongly advice against that if there's any sort of processing which manipulates the controls, like databinding them.

Visual inheritance does not find much use, you are better off refactoring common functionality into a user control and add that to both forms instead of inheriting one from the other.